# Procrun Error: FindClass org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher failed

Tags: spring-boot, service, procrun

I am trying to create a service from my Springboot jar with Apache Commons Daemon procrun. When I try to run the service I get the "FindClass org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher failed"-Error.

In my **POM** I added:

```html
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and

```html
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

The full **Error-Log:**

```html
[2024-01-22 11:33:20] [info]  [ 3780] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.4.0 64-bit) started.
[2024-01-22 11:33:20] [info]  [ 3780] Running Service 'RESTApi'...
[2024-01-22 11:33:20] [info]  [ 3536] Starting service...
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [error] [ 5204] FindClass org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher failed
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [error] [ 5204] The specified procedure could not be found.
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [error] [ 3536] Failed to start Java
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [error] [ 3536] ServiceStart returned 4.
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [info]  [ 3780] Run service finished.
[2024-01-22 11:33:21] [info]  [ 3780] Apache Commons Daemon procrun finished.
```

Please help me solve this error. I also take suggestions for other tools that are easy to handle. Notice I cannot use NSSM.